# How to enable network debugging in Xcode debug navigation tab

Tags: xcode, xcode11, xcode-instruments

I am performing network operations but the debug navigator doesn't show anything for the network. code is trivial and works as expected
for instance this trivial code downloads a file of 300 mb. takes around 2-3 minutes but the network remains at `zero KB/s`

```
let urlString = "https://...."

let url = URL(string: urlString)
let dt = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url!) { (url2, response, error) in
  print("completed with \(url2)")
}
dt.resume()
```

get this message as expected:

```
completed with Optional(file:///var/folders/5d/mc_q976d5h94zl38kr1zc4ym0000gn/T/CFNetworkDownload_jUr0fl.tmp)
```

[image]

[image]

Disk debugging works and shows downloaded file size as expected

[image]

Comment: did you know how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

In short, even as of Xcode 12.5.1 and Xcode 13 (beta 2), I find the network activity reported in Xcode to be unreliable.

A couple of observations:

1. I receive inconsistent results.

   For example, here is an animated gif, showing the progress of a download:

   [image]

   What's interesting is that while the download is in progress, the “total” gets reset in the middle of the download.

   In Instruments (using `os_signpost` with “Points of Interest” to identify exactly where the download was initiated and completed), I can see the download, but the progress is sporadic:

   [image]
2. Personally, to monitor network activity, I find external tools, such as [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org), to be more reliable:

   [image]

   This is a monitoring of the network interface, itself, eliminating Xcode from the equation.

   (As an aside, when integrating with custom web services, these tools are invaluable, as you can see the raw request and responses, which make debugging network code much easier.)
3. Interestingly, when I was routing my iPhone network activity through Charles on macOS, the Xcode network activity results suddenly were correct:

   [image]

   And:

   [image]

   But when I stopped routing the network activity through Charles, I got the original behavior, above.
4. If you are seeing no network activity, make sure your network request is actually being performed. Just because you got a response does not mean that it fetched it over the network: `URLSession` will transparently employ `URLCache`, retrieving the asset from cache, if it can.

   To reset the app cache, you can either delete the app from the device and re-install (thereby removing any cached responses), or, for solely for diagnostic purposes, you might consider temporarily turning off caching programmatically:

   ```swift
   let url = URL(string: urlString)!
   var request = URLRequest(url: url)
   request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData

   let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: request) { location, response, error in
       ...
   }
   task.resume()
   ```